# POST Data Model Empty If Other Row Is Selected - MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm running into a problem where if a user selects any other row besides the 1st row, the data POST comes back empty. Data only appears in the POST if the user selects 1st row.

It works only if I use FormCollection to return the data.

What am I doing wrong?

OrderHistory.CSHTML

```
@model DiningOrder.Models.JSON.OrderHistory

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.orders.Count(); i++)
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Reorder", "OrderHistory", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.orders[i].id)
        
        <input type="submit" value="REORDER" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block" />
    }
}
```

OrderHistory Controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Reorder(OrderHistory model)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I can't see any data except a hidded filed. Where are rows? what data are  you submiting?

Comment: And pls post your controller. Are you sure that your Model.orders.Count() > 1

Comment: The data is the hidden field.

Comment: Sorry, I meant  action that creates this view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the view you posted, you have a form per each row! Hence whenever you post back to the server, you're only sending one order ID.

If you only need an order ID in order to re-order, you should create your `Reorder` method to only take an order ID:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Reorder(int orderId)
{
    return View();
}
```

If you want the user to be able to select multiple orders and re-order them, then you would probably change the view model a little bit:

```cs
// I am totally guessing
public class OrderHistoryViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<OrderViewModel> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class OrderViewModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public bool SelectedToReorder { get; set; }
}
```

Then you initialize the order list on your `[HttpGet]` method:

```cs
public class OrderHistoryController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new OrderHistoryViewModel
        {
            Orders = // Get the orders from your persistence layer
        };

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

Then in the `index.cshtml` view, instead of putting multiple forms, you would just need one:

```
@model OrderHistoryViewModel

<h3>Order History</h3>
@using (Html.BeginForm("reorder", "orderhistory", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, null)
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Orders.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Orders[i].Id)
        @Html.CheckboxFor(x => x.Orders[i].SelectedToReorder)
    }

    <button type="submit">Re-order</button>
}
```

Finally, in your `[HttpPost]` method, you can filter those orders the user selects and process your logic:

```cs
public class OrderHistoryController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new OrderHistoryViewModel
        {
            Orders = // Get the orders from your persistence layer
        };

        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Reorder(OrderHistoryViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var selectedOrderIds = model.Orders
                .Where(x => x.SelectedToReorder == true)
                .ToArray();

            // Keep going

            return RedirectToAction ...;
        }

        return View...;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no any  table and rows here. Your code create several separate forms and when you submit you just submit one of the forms and  you have to treat  the submission as a FormCollection